# Reverse lookup from physical address to application virtual address in linux kernel

Tags: linux, opengl, memory, linux-kernel, kernel

I have an openGL buffer object in application *A*. And I  have the virtual address, *V*, of the corresponding object. I know that this virtual address is mapped to the GPU device memory (iomem), *P*.
I want to find out the physical address *P* for this *V* in *A* context.

- Constraint (1): I can not modify graphics stack (mesa, libdrm, ...) in user space.
- Constraint (2): I can only modify drm kernel driver.

Currently, what I'm thinking is to write an IOCTL
 inside drm kernel driver, that receives PID of *A* and *V* and returns *P*. For this, inside the IOCTL, I think I have to walk the *A*'s page table to find out the value of *P*.

And, I certainly do not want to develop such kind of page table walker, and I believe Linux kernel already has some good helpers for this. Could you give any advice?

Comment: The answer to this largely depends on how your driver operates and what parts of the Linux graphics modules it uses. Is this a UMA GPU? i.e. uses system memory? If it uses GEM_MMAP to map memory it shouldn't be too hard to add an ioctl. The big question is why though? If the system supports paging your physical address could be invalid before you even get to use it.

Comment: I'm using UMA GPU and uses GEM_MMAP. And for this gem object, I'm going to pin to both GPU memory and system memory. So no worry about paging out.